# Negative margin limit with images

Tags: html, css, image, fluid-layout, margins

**See My Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5BEsZ/

I've discovered something very strange that I haven't seen documented anywhere else... Was wondering if you all had a solution.

You'll notice the negative margin hits a limit at around -212% for image elements. Is there a reason for this? Can you think of a work around?

**Why I Need This (what I've tried):**

I'm making a fluid layout and I want to display a rating system. I have a sprite sheet of stars (similar to the one in the fiddle) that I want to reuse at various sizes.

Because the size changes I can't use a background image. So I decided to use an image inside a container with a variable width and `overflow:hidden`. The sprite sheet adjusts to the width of the container and the container's viewable content is determined by a `padding-top:20%`. This is so it can be fluid with its width (since every star is a box, the total height is 20% the width).

Then I try and position the star image inside the container with margin-top. I tried using `position:relative` and a `top:-X%`, but because the container technically has no height this was causing issue on mobile phones (-100% of 0 is 0, etc).

So I assumed negative margin would work, but then discovered this strange issue!

***NOTE**: Because it affects only the last row I can make it work in my situation by using a padding-bottom instead of top (thereby bumping every star row up 1), but this isn't an adequate solution for me because it just ignores the problem. What if I wanted quarter stars?*

Answer (score 4):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BEsZ/1/). `img` tags are "inline" elements by default, which impacts the way margin is calculated relative to the containing element. By forcing the image element to be rendered like a block (`display: block`), you're able to achieve the results you were expecting. A `div` element is a block by default.

As a side note, you'll want to avoid using inline styles (a different sort of "inline"!) wherever possible. Typically your styles would be included in a stylesheet instead of in a `style` attribute directly on the element. I included the fix (`display: block`) in the attribute to match the code style of your html.

Comment: I just used the inline styles for the fiddle. Display block does fix it, but img tags are replaced inline elements so margin-top should work. And it seems to work just fine up until that arbitrary point. That's really the crux of my question (why is there some arbitrary point).

In any case I appreciate your answer. And since I don't rightly see a resolution to the heart of the problem per the W3 standard I'm just going to award you the green check.

Comment: Sorry, I'm un-awarding your answer because the replaced element can have a positive margin amount without needing display:block (so the nature of the display is not the issue). I'm actually concerned why the negative amount fails at a certain point.

Comment: It appears that `vertical-align:top` also results in the correct rendering: http://jsfiddle.net/5BEsZ/3/ This is an interesting question, and I'm interested to see if someone is able to shed more light on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you float the image the problem goes away.

```
<img src="http://www.whitepages.com/common/images/sprite_stars.gif?1343868502" id="stars" style="width:100%; float: left;" />
```

So, the answer to fix your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5BEsZ/2/

If anyone could explain why this happens?

Comment: Floating the image element converts the display model from `inline` to `block`, which changes how the margin is calculated.